# Angular JS Call function after another function is finished

Tags: angularjs

i need to know, when  $timeout in function1 is finish. How to know, when timeout finish work?

```js
$scope.function1 = function (array, file_id) {
                                  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                                        if (array[i].file_id == file_id){     
  
                                         $timeout(function () {
                                                array.splice(i, 1); 
                                           // when finish?
                                          }, 2000);
                                          break;
                                        }
                                  }
                        return array;
}




$scope.function1($rootScope.parcelQeue, response[0]);
getOutboxParcelFactory.getParcel(response).then(function(infoObj){
// do something if the timeout in function1 is finished
});
```

Comment: You should use a promise.

Comment: Encapsulate the `getParcel()` service inside a function and call the function from within the `$timeout()` - you are thus executing the service after the timeout is done with its other work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a flag to check if the function inside `$timeout` ran or not:

```
var timerRun = false;
$scope.function1 = function (array, file_id) {
   timerRun = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     if (array[i].file_id == file_id){     

       $timeout(function () {
         array.splice(i, 1); 
         // when finish?
         timerRun = true; 
       }, 2000);
       break;
     }
   }
   return array;
}


$scope.function1($rootScope.parcelQeue, response[0]);
getOutboxParcelFactory.getParcel(response).then(function(infoObj){
  // do something if the timeout in function1 is finished
  if (timerRun) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    console.log("I am not doing anything, and will not do in the future because the timeout in function1 is not finished.");
  }
});
```

This is not an elegant solution but I think it resolved what you asked.

But, if you don't want to only **check** but also **wait** for `$timeout` to complete, then you need a different approach.